# How can I change BLE connection parameters from bluetoothctl? (org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to connect to a BLE smart lock from my Raspberry Pi Model 4 to open the lock. I have installed the latest BlueZ 5.66. I can successfully connect to the lock with `hci_tool` like this:

`sudo hcitool lecc --random DE:44:38:02:AA:EA`

With `btmon` I see the following:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.66
= Note: Linux version 5.15.76-v7l+ (armv7l)                            0.028327
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                               0.028335
= New Index: E4:5F:01:12:67:74 (Primary,UART,hci0)              [hci0] 0.028338
= Open Index: E4:5F:01:12:67:74                                 [hci0] 0.028341
= Index Info: E4:5F:01:12:67:74 (Broadcom Corporation)          [hci0] 0.028345
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.21             {0x0001} 0.028348
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                 {0x0002} 4.924550
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                          {0x0002} 4.924600
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22          {0x0002} [hci0] 4.924657
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25    #1 [hci0] 4.924801
        Scan interval: 2.500 msec (0x0004)
        Scan window: 2.500 msec (0x0004)
        Filter policy: Accept list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 18.75 msec (0x000f)
        Max connection interval: 18.75 msec (0x000f)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 32000 msec (0x0c80)
        Min connection length: 0.625 msec (0x0001)
        Max connection length: 0.625 msec (0x0001)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                    #2 [hci0] 4.926433
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31                   #3 [hci0] 14.452646
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Central (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Local resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Peer resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 18.75 msec (0x000f)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 32000 msec (0x0c80)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13       {0x0001} [hci0] 14.452752
        LE Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          Connection Locally Initiated
        Data length: 0
@ RAW Open: btmon (privileged) version 2.22                  {0x0003} 14.453015
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used... (0x08|0x0016) plen 2  #4 [hci0] 14.453048
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
@ RAW Close: btmon                                           {0x0003} 14.453086
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                   #5 [hci0] 14.453388
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                   #6 [hci0] 14.503982
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Max TX octets: 27
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 27
        Max RX time: 2120
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                   #7 [hci0] 14.541397
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Features: 0x25 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          LE 2M PHY

[.. I cut out a lot here ...]

@ MGMT Event: New Connection Para.. (0x001c) plen 16  {0x0001} [hci0] 19.341463
        Store hint: Reserved (0xea)
        BR/EDR Address: 02:DE:44:38:02:AA (OUI 02-DE-44)
        Min connection interval: 320
        Max connection interval: 520
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 400
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 10               #114 [hci0] 19.341506
      LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Response (0x13) ident 3 len 2
        Result: Connection Parameters accepted (0x0000)
< HCI Command: LE Connection Upd.. (0x08|0x0013) plen 14  #115 [hci0] 19.341550
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Min connection interval: 400.00 msec (0x0140)
        Max connection interval: 650.00 msec (0x0208)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 4000 msec (0x0190)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                 #116 [hci0] 19.343911
      LE Connection Update (0x08|0x0013) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #117 [hci0] 19.522890
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                 #118 [hci0] 20.095076
      LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Connection interval: 648.75 msec (0x0207)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 4000 msec (0x0190)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4            #119 [hci0] 27.880662
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64 Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8     {0x0001} [hci0] 27.880723
        LE Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                  {0x0002} [hci0] 45.071448
```

However, from my app in Python I use the `bleak` library, which in turn uses Bluez to establish the connection. This fails and I tried to connect using `bluetoothctl` via the command line. The connection parameters in `btmon` look entirely different, and I get an error on the command line after a while:

```
[bluetooth]# connect DE:44:38:02:AA:EA
Attempting to connect to DE:44:38:02:AA:EA
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local
```

**btmon:**

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.66
= Note: Linux version 5.15.76-v7l+ (armv7l)                            0.605856
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                               0.605871
= New Index: E4:5F:01:12:67:74 (Primary,UART,hci0)              [hci0] 0.605877
= Open Index: E4:5F:01:12:67:74                                 [hci0] 0.605881
= Index Info: E4:5F:01:12:67:74 (Broadcom Corporation)          [hci0] 0.605897
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.21             {0x0001} 0.605903
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7   #1 [hci0] 4.022789
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in accept list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #2 [hci0] 4.023364
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2       #3 [hci0] 4.023445
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #4 [hci0] 4.024390
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 43                    #5 [hci0] 7.318969
      LE Advertising Report (0x02)
        Num reports: 1
        Event type: Connectable undirected - ADV_IND (0x00)
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Data length: 31
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        TX power: -13 dBm
        Company: internal use (65535)
          Data: 643f000000000400130500443802aaea3202020113
        RSSI: -61 dBm (0xc3)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2       #6 [hci0] 7.319103
        Scanning: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                  #7 [hci0] 7.320572
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25    #8 [hci0] 7.320667
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: Accept list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                    #9 [hci0] 7.321723
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connectio.. (0x08|0x000e) plen 0  #10 [hci0] 11.373868
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                #11 [hci0] 11.398188
      LE Create Connection Cancel (0x08|0x000e) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31                  #12 [hci0] 11.398363
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Unknown Connection Identifier (0x02)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Central (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: DE:44:38:02:AA:EA (Static)
        Local resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Peer resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x00
```

Why is that? And how I can set the connection parameters with `bluetoothctl` so that it works?

Any advice is appreciated - thanks in advance!
Nicolas

Comment: I am assuming you have paired with the device using bluetoothctl? Set the device to trusted etc?

Comment: I tried setting it to "trusted", which worked, but not for the connection. Pairing is not possible with this device - I believe pairing is not necessary. On Windows 10 I got it running with bleak, but not on Raspberry Pi with BlueZ. On Windows it doesn't need pairing. Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming that a lock would require encrypted-write or encrypt-authenticated-write which would require the devices to exchange keys at some point. Make sure you do `agent on` in `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: The locks have two modes, with and without encrypted keys. They are set to "without". The connection with the `hci_tool` works, and as far as I can see, it uses different connection parameters for connect interval min/max and supervision timeout. But I don't know exactly why and how to control this with `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: Maybe try using `btmgmt` rather than `bluetoothctl` as that has lower level control. Not much documentation around it apart from the `help` and the API docs at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know how it turned out!